# How Openvas+proxychains or Nmap+proxychains (by socks5 not socks4)?

Tags: openvas

I want to do the vulnerability scan via a socks5 proxy,and I find two way to do this work,one is openvas,and the other one is Nmap's Nse script,but at the Nmap's document has a words:

> Asks Nmap to establish TCP connections with a final target through supplied chain of one or more HTTP or SOCKS4 proxies. Proxies can help hide the true source of a scan or evade certain firewall restrictions, but they can hamper scan performance by increasing latency. Users may need to adjust Nmap timeouts and other scan parameters accordingly. In particular, a lower --max-parallelism may help because some proxies refuse to handle as many concurrent connections as Nmap opens by default.
>       This option takes a list of proxies as argument, expressed as URLs in the 
>       format proto://host:port. Use commas to separate node URLs in a chain. No
>        authentication is supported yet.
>
> **Valid protocols are HTTP and SOCKS4.**
>
> Warning: this feature is still under development and has limitations. It is implemented within the nsock library and thus has no effect on the ping, port scanning and OS discovery phases of a scan. **Only NSE and version scan benefit from this option so far—other features may disclose your true address.** SSL connections are not yet supported, nor is proxy-side DNS resolution (hostnames are always resolved by Nmap).

although there are many blog talk about:

- [Nmap through proxy](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/120708/nmap-through-proxy/120723#120723)
- [Proxychains + nmap = segmentation fault](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/63947/proxychains-nmap-segmentation-fault)
- [Anonymous Port Scanning: Nmap + Tor + ProxyChains](https://www.shellhacks.com/anonymous-port-scanning-nmap-tor-proxychains/#comments)
- [Nmap Anonymization with Proxychains](https://marcosvalle.github.io/pentest/2017/10/17/nmap-anon.html)
- [Nse脚本目录](https://nmap.org/nsedoc/)
- [Nmap扫描永恒之蓝漏洞用例](https://nmap.org/nsedoc/scripts/smb-vuln-ms17-010.html)
- [--script参数](https://nmap.org/book/man-nse.html)

but all of this method just for socks4 or http. i also have try these many times with different ways.
so i turn to search the way 'openvas+proxy',but i can't found ,can any one tell me,thanks!
sorry for my poor english.